# Need help to test html form textbox and go to page if value is the same as a set value

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Hello I am trying to make a simple form to test if the the textfield is equal to a variable, variable value example: ( "**MyPassword123**" ).

Then if it the textfield is the same as the variable than go to html document, example: ( "**nextPage.html**" ).

however if its *NOT* equal to variable then go to html document, example: ( "**index.html**" ).

the reason of the password is to restrict people that don't play on my game server form nextPage.html, it will have just like news feeds and game information on it, Its nothing like an profile or anything I just want to give out a password to only allow people that play on the server to view a page that's all.

I have tried many times to get this to work in javascript and I am sure its achievable for this simple task using if/else statements and validate the name of the text field but I am no good at java nor javascript.

**Form Code:**

```
<form name="accessForm">
Password: <input type="text" name="inputCode"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

If someone could post some code of javascript to make this work, you would so awesome.

**NOTE:**

> Not sure if it matters much but I am using HTML5 and CSS3, and for
>   Hosting I will be using GoogleDrive, so I cant use MySQL, it needs to
>   be javascript. I have not tested Drive to see if it allows PHP but I
>   know Javascript works fine.

Comment: You shouldn't be relying on javascript to validate a password. This is easy to bypass, especially when a browser has javascript turned off.

Answer (score 0):

**You need not to use HTML form for it**

```
<script>
function checkIt()
{
if(document.getElementById("inputCode").value=="MyPassword123")
location.href="nextPage.html";
else
location.href="index.html";
}
</script>
Password: <input id="inputCode" type="text"/>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="checkIt()"/>
```

Comment: Thank you guys for your help and quick replies your coded helped a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Like @Wes Foster mentioned, you should do password validation on the backend, but to compare a form input to a variable in vanilla JS you could do this:

```
var password = "magicWord";
var form = document.getElementById("formName");

form.onsubmit = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = document.forms.accessForm.inputCode.value;

  if (data == password) location.href = "success.html";
  else location.href = "fail.html";
};
```